# Reset RadCheckedDropDownList in Telerik Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have used Telerik `RadCheckedDropDownList` in my windows application. I have a Clear button which resets and clears values in the controls used in my winform application. But I do not have any idea to reset `RadCheckedDropDownList`. When I click clear button, checkboxes which are checked in `RadCheckedDropDownList` should get unchecked. Please suggest me a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could show some code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line of code does uncheck checkboxes in RadCheckedDropDownList

RadCheckedDropDownList.CheckedItems.Clear()